# Yii, Render a view just by calling a method in a component

Tags: php, yii

I need to render a view by calling a method in a component.
Could anyone please tell me is it possible? If yes, how can do that?

Comment: Please show us that you at least put some effort into figuring it out. You just explain what you **want**, but you never say anything about what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easily attainable by using:

```
Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('viewPath');
```